# Firebase / Firestore / Angular: How do I create subcollections within documents?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I've got a Firestore database in Firebase for my Angular web app. Now I'm trying to create new documents within my collection "users". I know how to create those but only with simple fields ("mail, nickname and userID"). I also want to add a subcollection "routes" to this document but I don't know how. There will be documents within this subcollection.

Here is a photo of my DB in Firebase:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nZMn.png

This is the function I use to create a new user in this database. It is working but the subcollection is missing.

```
  create_new_User(docID, email, nickname, userID) {
    return this.fireservices.collection('users').doc(docID).set({
      mail: email,
      nickname: nickname,
      userID: userID
    });
  }
```

Has someone any ideas to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally make the docId for user collection to be the same as the actual userId but you don't have to do it this way.  You can only create one document at a time so you need to either batch this or run them in 2 seperate document writes.  You can do something like this for example with out a batch:

```
create_new_User(userId, email, nickname, routeId, routeParams) {

 this.fireservices.collection('users').doc(userId).set({
          mail: email,
          nickname: nickname,
          userID: userID
        })
            this.fireservices.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('routes').doc(routeId).set({ routeParams })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you David. I read about this batch writes after your hint. It's nice to wrap up my transactions but each operation within the batch will count separately towards my Firestore usage. So normally there should be no advantage for batching things up in my case. Am I right? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: In both cases it will count as 2 writes to firestore useage.  I believe performance is better if you batch them together, however, you will ultimately get the same result.

The disadvantage of batching is that you get no chance to read the document between the two writes.  In this case it wouldn't matter because you are assigining the document id yourself but if you were to first add a user document and you wanted to read the newly created document id in between you wouldn't batch and do them as seperate operations.